# How can I implement voice chat in PHP based website?

Tags: php, chat, voice

Any suggestions for simple voice chat solution for a PHP based website. We already have a text chat in place, client now wants voice chat too.

Answer (score 2):

Voice chat simply isn't going to happen with PHP. Such a thing requires a dedicated chat server/service; your client may be interested in something like Skype for Business or Google Talk. Both of these things (as I recall) will require an out-of-browser product to be installed.

Comment: Using third party tool is not an issue but it should be tightly integrated with the website, such as I should be able to login to voice chat from the website itself. Is it possible?

Comment: Sure it is possible, and PHP can even broker the data in some cases, but if you're looking at "real-time" voice, you're getting into protocols non-HTTP where PHP doesn't necessarily play.

Answer (score 1):

You could problably use Adobe flash.

PHP can solve a lot of problems but not anything like voice chat.